# iOS orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Could i change orientation in iOS inside UITabBarController? I have something like this: UITableViewController-> Team Tab -> UINavigationController -> GalleryViewController and i would like to allow only for GalleryViewController change landscape orientation is iOS is it possible?

If i set

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
```

for UITabBarController i couldn't change orientation for GalleryViewController, it's always portrait.

Comment: iOS6 is under NDA, so the question remains unanswered

Comment: I have removed the references to software covered by NDA.

Answer (score 1):

If we abstract from iOS6 and look at [Tab Bar Controllers and View Rotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW26) article :

> Tab bar controllers support a portrait orientation by default and do
>   not rotate to a landscape orientation unless all of the contained view
>   controllers support such an orientation. When a device orientation
>   change occurs, the tab bar controller queries its array of view
>   controllers. If any one of them does not support the orientation, the
>   tab bar controller does not change its orientation.

This mean that **all** other viewcontrollers in tabbar should support required orientations.

Comment: okay, but when i set up UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for UITabBarCotrnoller, all viewController are support orientation rotation, but i need to only set landscape orientation for nested view controller...